# when saveing $meta_box i get Undefined index error

Tags: metabox, post-meta, nonce

I need help to fix these Notices:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: person-name in testimonials.php on line 112
PHP Notice: Undefined index: position in testimonials.php on line 112
PHP Notice: Undefined index: company in testimonials.php on line 112
PHP Notice: Undefined index: link in testimonials.php on line 112
PHP Notice: Undefined index: testimonial_wpnonce in /testimonials.php on line 116
PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in testimonials.php on line 97
```

I tried the following:

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $key . '_wpnonce' ], plugin_basename(FILE) ) ) return $post_id;
```

but still got Undefined index.

Here is the code from line 95 - 124

```
        <div class="form-field form-required">
            <label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] ); ?>" />
            <p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
    <?php
}

function wpb_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $meta_boxes, $key;

    foreach( $meta_boxes as $meta_box ) {
        $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] = $_POST[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ];
    }

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $key . '_wpnonce' ], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
        return $post_id;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
        return $post_id;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $data );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpb_create_meta_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpb_save_meta_box' );
```

Comment: For the future: Please format your post and intend your code. Thanks.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/114525/edit)  to show us what is in the `$_POST` and `$meta_boxes` arrays.